# Div Position Fixed

Tags: css

I have a problem with two divs that have `position: fixed`.

If you look at the header, the scrollbar is in the back and the header is on top of the scrollbar. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="BG1">
 <div class="Data"></div>
</div>

<div class="BG2">
 <div id="Header">
  <div class="Header_Data"></div>
 </div>
 <br />a<br /><br />a<br /><br />
</div>
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Pwg/

Comment: never saw that before, very interested in the answer

Comment: You can fix it by creating a layout without making everything on the page `position: fixed`.  The browser's scrollbar cannot be overlapped, unlike a div's scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your example: http://jsfiddle.net/uVjft/

So actually you have on `position: fixed` block inside another. And the scrollbar corresponds to `BG2` block NOT the window scrollbar which actually cannot be overlapped.

To fix this try to remove `position: fixed`from `BG2` div: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Pwg/1/

Comment: yes i see that ... but how i can do something that way or some fix ... right now the only fix what i find its make ".BG2 #Header" to be width: 99% so he have the space for scrollbar ... the problem its if you want to add box-shadow will be a problem ...

Comment: does removing `position: fixed` from the div not solve the problem?

Comment: i find one way how to fix the problem ... how i say up .. to make the width = 99% becouse scrollbar its 1%, how much i see its working ... ( sorry for my bad english )

Comment: Just resize the window this the result you will notice that scrollbar is not always 1%. And in different browsers you will see different result. Each browser has different scrollbar width. You have chosen the wrong way. Does my solution not work for you?

Comment: did you try this link http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Pwg/1/ ? it works in chrome and firefox.

Comment: is this the answer to your question?

Comment: i dont know how to mark like an answer dont show me the symbol of accept answer ... please update the code from up and i will make it like answer ...

Answer (score 0):

**just include the code**

```
  .BG2 #Header .Header_Data {
   width: 100%;
   height: 120px;
   overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#eee;

}
```

> in your css it will fix your issue, and if u want a fixed header don't use transparent background

---

Thanks